# Solve $Ax=b$ in the least squares sense, but all elements of $x$ must have an absolute value of 1

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

I need to solve the system of linear equations $Ax=b$, where $A$ is a non-sparse matrix that has more rows than columns. Moreover, the entries of $A,x$ and $b$ are complex, and the absolute value of every element of $x$ must be unity.

What would be the best way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can't you just solve the least squares solution to $Ax = b$ and then normalize $x$?

Comment: No because every *element* of $x$ needs to have an absolute value of 1, not the complete vector $x$. I can only play with the phase of every element in order to solve the equation, not the amplitude unfortunately.

Comment: @JosephCamacho There's no reason to expect that to give the optimal answer. A better heuristic I think is to minimize $\| Ax - b \|^2$ subject to the constraint that $| x_i | \leq 1$ for $i = 1, \ldots, n$. (Here $x_i$ is the $i$th component of $x \in \mathbb C^n$.) This is a convex problem so it can be solved efficiently. If we're lucky the solution $x^\star$ will satisfy $| x^\star_i| = 1$ for all $i$, in which case we will have an optimal solution to the original problem. If that doesn't happen, we can scale each component of $x^\star$ to obtain a vector whose components have magnitude $1$.

Comment: I think you'll have to do something like $x_p = e^{i\theta_p}$ and work with the nonlinear least squares problem for $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots$.

Comment: The least squares solution is a linear combination of the columns of A nearest to $b$.  Can you find the components of $x$, divide each by their modulus and multiply each column of $A$ by each corresponding modulus to give $x'$ and $A'$. The least squares solution of $A'x' = b$ will give the same point in the subspace generated by the columns of A but the components of $x'$ will have modulus 1.